# HTML Marquee-scroller failed to display elements

Tags: html, css, marquee, scroller

I am having a very strange problem with my `Marquee scroller`. Below is my `HTML` and `CSS` implementation.

In my scroller I have 5 elements. *I want to keep the Width of each element-containers as variable* depending on the length of the underlying element.

Strangely, my HTML page failed to display any element. However, if I reduce the number of elements (let say to 3) then the underlying elements are getting displayed as designed.

I would appreciate if someone here can show me any pointer what went wrong in below code i.e. why the elements are not getting displayed if number of elements are high (*in my actual implementation, I actually have more than 100 of elements in the scroller*).

Thanks in advance for your help.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head><link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS.css"></head>
<body>  
    <div id = "Scroller_ID" class = "Scroller">
        <div class = "Marquee">
            <div class = "Marquee-content">
                    <div class = 'Marquee-tag'>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Status'>&#11044;</div>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Content'>
                            fffff
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'Marquee-tag'>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Status'>&#11044;</div>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Content'>
                            GGGGGGGGGGGGG
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'Marquee-tag'>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Status'>&#11044;</div>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Content'>
                            GGGGGGGGGGGGG
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'Marquee-tag'>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Status'>&#11044;</div>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Content'>
                            GGGGGGGGGGGGG
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'Marquee-tag'>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Status'>&#11044;</div>
                        <div class = 'Marquee-tag-Content'>
                            GGGGGGGGGGGGG
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div></div></body>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
.Scroller {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 400;
        height: 85px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;      
        font-size: 16px;
        float: left;
        background-color: hsla(0,0%,90%,1);  
    }
.Marquee {
        margin: 9px 12px 9px 12px;
        background: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.8);
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
.Marquee-content {
        display: flex;      
        animation: marquee 7s linear infinite running;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
.Marquee-tag {      
        height: 67px;
    }
.Marquee-tag-Status {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-size: 9px;
    }
.Marquee-tag-Content {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        min-width: 420px;       
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        margin-top: 3px;
        font-size: 9px;
    }
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0);
            }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-50%);
            }
    }
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0);
            }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-50%);
            }
    }
@-o-keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0);
            }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-50%);
            }
    }
@keyframes marquee {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(0);
            }
        100% {
            transform: translate(-50%);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

use marquee tag to display the marquee elements also give direction in tag see the example below

```
<marquee>This is basic example of marquee</marquee>
      <marquee direction = "up">The direction of text will be from bottom to top.</marquee>
```

Comment: Hi Waqas, could you please be more specific? Also, I dont see any example that you mentioned.

Comment: **Don't** use obsolete tags : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee .  The marquee tag was a mistake to start with, kill it with fire and move on.